# C++ random filling array out of 4 set letters

Tags: c++, loops, random, srand

I'm really really stuck here
I've been trying to fill an array with random capital letters out of a set of 4(A, C, G, T)
my program however will only return the 4 letters in the same order until it filled the whole array, the first character does start different every try
here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

char letters[500];
int set[] = {65, 67, 84, 71};
int size = 4;
void runLength(char[]);
void generateRandom(int);

void generateRandom(int i)
{
    int character = 0;
    character = rand()%size;
    letters[i] = set[character];
    cout<<letters[i];
}

int main()
{
    srand( time( 0 ) );

    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        generateRandom(i);
    }

    runLength(letters);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The result for this program is ALWAYS 'A''C''T''G' with a different character to start
basically the randoming process seems to be going, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3 repeatedly, how can I fix this?

Comment: Seems to work well for me http://ideone.com/Jt2HoE

Comment: could it be because of my compiler then? I'm running it from the .exe file after I compile...it hasn't worked for me at all so far

Comment: It's working for me as well.  How are you compiling it?  (I did have to comment out runLength, because it's not defined in the code you gave)

Comment: Where is the implementation for `runLength`? Problem may be in there.

Comment: http://ideone.com/GJSyAO

Comment: that is the full code without printing the letters out as that was only in there to check the randomization

Comment: I can actually see an error cuz apparently the code runs correctly, since I'm not resetting my run count to 0

Comment: http://ideone.com/Cetz5F corrected my code for runLength here, so it seems like it is working, I'm compiling this with SciTE, but I think it may have issues interacting with my g++ since it's working perfectly on the website...

Comment: thanks you guys, I realized it's my computer's problem...would've been stuck here trying to figure out nothing if I didn't ask on the site